# Can I start a Flatpak app in a separate profile?

Tags: profile, flatpak

I normally start and stop [Revolt](https://github.com/aperezdc/revolt) with these Flatpak commands:

```
# start
flatpak run org.perezdecastro.Revolt

# stop    
gdbus call --session \
  --dest org.perezdecastro.Revolt \
  --object-path /org/perezdecastro/Revolt \
  --method org.gtk.Actions.Activate \
  quit '[]' '{}'
```

I'd like to launch a second instance of Revolt in the current desktop session, such that:

- I can start and stop the second instance independently
- it does not share settings with the original instance
- it stores its own settings in a distinct location
- (ideally) it has a distinct icon

How can I do this?